# bcc64 optimizations -O1 vs -O2 still slower than bcc32 by 40% and more

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I have a product consisting of a VCL executable plus a Standard C++ DLL, all built with C++ Builder XE4. I publish in 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

When doing performance testing with release builds, the 64-bit version runs much more slowly... 40% more slowly.

I understand that I need to have optimizations turned on for the performance testing to be meaningful. XE4 allows me to set (mutually exclusively):

-O1 = smallest possible code
-O2 = fastest possible code

I have built using each of these, but the results are unchanged.

I see from postings here that Linux/g++ programmers use -O3 (smallest AND fastest?) (see [64-bit executable runs slower than 32-bit version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525610/64-bit-executable-runs-slower-than-32-bit-version#21526568)). But -O3 is not an option for my environment.

Are there other compiler settings I should be looking at?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The main downside of 64bit mode is that pointers double in size.  Alignment rules might also lead classes/structs to be bigger.  Maybe your code just barely fit into cache in 32bit mode, but not 64.  This is esp. likely if your code uses a lot of pointers.

Another possibility is that you call some external library, and your 32bit version of it has some asm speedups, but the 64bit version doesn't.

Use a profiler to see what's *actually* slow in your 64bit version.  For Windows, Intel's VTUNE is maybe a good choice.  You can see where your code is having a lot of cache misses.  Comparing total cache misses between 32bit and 64bit should shed some light.

Re: `-O1` vs. `-O2`:  Different compilers have different meanings for options.  gcc and clang have:

- `-Os`: optimize for code size
- `-O0`: minimal / no optimization (most things get stored/reloaded from RAM after every step)
- `-O1`: some optimization without taking a lot of extra compile time
- `-O2`: more optimizations
- `-O3`: even more optimizations, including auto-vectorizing

Clang doesn't seem to document its optimization options, so I assume it mirrors gcc.  (There are [options to report on optimizations it did](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#options-to-emit-optimization-reports), and to use profile-guided optimization.)  See [the latest version of the gcc manual (online)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) for more descriptions of optimization options:  e.g.

- `-Ofast`: `-O3 -ffast-math` (and maybe "unsafe" optimizations.)
- `-Og`: optimize without breaking debugging.  Recommended for the edit/compile/debug cycle.
- `-funroll-loops`: can help in some tight loops, but isn't enabled even at `-O3`.  Don't use for everything, because larger code size can lead to I-cache misses which hurt more.  `-fprofile-use` does enable this, so ideally just use PGO.
- `-fblah-blah`: there are a ton more specific options.  Usually just use `-O3` to pick the recommended set.

Comment: Thank you, Peter, for this information. My DLL does call another external DLL (in fact, that is the condition that causes the performance issue; as long as that call is never made, the performance between 32-bit and 64-bit are the same). I use AQTime for profiling, but it can only profile 32-bit apps. I'll look into VTUNE to see if I can make it work. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: re: AQTime, I should have said "the version I'm using (8.10) can profile only 32-bit builds from XE4". I'm purchasing the upgrade today, which I am told will be able to profile my 64-bit XE4 builds, as well.